# Can't find css and js files for magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento2

I've just installed Mangento 2.0.7 on Xampp(Windows). But remarked that files referenced in `pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US`'s subfolders does not exist.

For example, `pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js` return 404, and does really not exist in the folder.

What's going wrong ? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

remove var folder and run frontend page.

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh, how to do if deploying to the production server which is GoDaddy ? Any useful tips ?

Comment: For production server i haven't do yet but try with same above may be its helpful

Comment: I don't have access to command line over ther to execute this command. Or is it possible ?